# Python 2.6 update to 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using cent os 6.7 server and I want to update my python 2.6 to 2.7 or above and also want to change my default version from python 2.6 to newest. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
yum install -y centos-release-SCL
yum install -y python27
```

Then check your python version

```
which python
python -V
```

More information [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-2/wiki/Installing-python-2.7-on-centos-6.3.-Follow-this-sequence-exactly-for-centos-machine-only)

Comment: I know upgrading Python on RedHat family OSes breaks yum in some situations. Are you certain this doesn't?

Comment: ya i had installed like u said but still it showing the version as python 2.6. the 2.7 is get installed on /usr/local/bin/ and the 2.6 is on /usr/bin. So how can i point out my default python version as 2.7?